# Estamos mudando de nome (de novo)!

Tags: debate

## Somos o Stack Overflow

O pessoal por trás do Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow Careers, a Rede Stack Exchange e a maior parte dos resultados que você encontra no Google.

### tl;dr - A empresa está mudando de nome

**O que muda:**

1. A partir de hoje nossa empresa passa a se chamar Stack Overflow
2. A logo mudou, mas só um pouquinho
3. Mais nada!

**O que é "Stack Overflow":**

- Uma comunidade onde milhões de programadores resolvem problemas e compartilham conhecimento
- O melhor lugar para procurar empregos de programação, ou para contratar programadores
- O maior entre os 140 sites da Rede Stack Exchange
- A empresa por trás de tudo isso (isso é novidade!)

Há exatamente sete anos, o [Joel anunciava o lançamento do Stack Overflow](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). Nossa estratégia, durante todo esse tempo, sempre foi construir ferramentas voltadas para programadores e depois, se tudo desse certo, expandi-las para um público maior. Nosso novo nome é um reflexo dessa filosofia.

É só isso. Mas como sabemos que vocês vão ter mais algumas perguntas, vamos tentar respondê-las aqui.

### P: O que mudou a partir de agora, com o novo nome?

A partir de hoje nós vamos poder dizer que "trabalho no Stack Overflow" e provavelmente vamos ter que gastar um dinheiro com cartões de visitas novos. Tem que ver com o pessoal responsável... Mas voltando ao assunto, nas próximas semanas nós vamos mexer em algumas coisas como o blog, o podcast e outros lugares onde "Stack Exchange" estava fazendo referência *à empresa*, ao invés da rede de sites. Os sites continuaram a fazer parte da Rede Stack Exchange.

### P: A mudança é um sinal de que vocês perderam interesse na Rede Stack Exchange?

Não. Não. Não. *Nananinanão.*

[image: NÃO MESMO]

Nada mudou. Nós continuamos tão dedicados e comprometidos com o sucesso e crescimento da Rede Stack Exchange quanto antes. O Stack Exchange continua sendo um lugar único na internet, onde pessoas diferentes trabalharam juntas para construir comunidades saudáveis e positivas. É um projeto especial e temos muito orgulho de fazer parte dele. Apenas para passar uma ideia do sucesso que vocês alcançaram:

- No total, a rede possui mais participantes ativos - com pelos menos 5 contribuições por mês - que a Wikipedia em inglês.
- O Stack Exchange é o [47º maior site da internet](https://www.quantcast.com/top-sites), isso *sem contar o Stack Overflow*! O número de visitantes por mês é comparável ao site do New York Times.

Um dos nossos investidores [comentou que](https://medium.com/@cdixon/a16z-leads-40m-investment-in-stack-exchange-a84b6c1b9122):

> Acredito que o sucesso do Stack Exchange não pode mais ser impedido. As comunidades atuais só tem a crescer, enquanto novas vão continuar a nascer até que a rede tenha sites a respeito de todos os assuntos possíveis. Meios antigos de buscar informação - pesquisando em livros ou perguntando para amigos - vão deixar de existir a medida em que novas gerações crescem acostumadas com a internet”
>
> ​                                                                                            --Chris Dixon, Andreessen Horowitz

Ouviram, livros??? Seu tempo já era!

### P: Mas qual o motivo da mudança?

**Tudo começou com um lugar para desenvolvedores tirarem dúvidas.**

Quando batizamos a empresa "Stack Exchange", sites de perguntas eram *tudo* que fazíamos. O Stack Overflow Q&A era um sucesso e queríamos extender a plataforma para outros assuntos. Então, fazia todo sentido dar à empresa o mesmo nome da rede. Se você pedisse a uma criança - uma bem ruim de desenho - para desenhar a hierarquia dos nosso produtos, que nem aqueles organogramas de empresas grandes e sem graça, o resultado seria algo assim:

[image: Fluxograma!]

Para deixar claro, a plataforma de perguntas e respostas continua sendo nosso principal produto. Nós continuamos trabalhando para que ela melhore e atenda ainda mais a todos os [programadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [engenheiras químicas](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), [fotógrafos](http://photo.stackexchange.com) e [esse pessoal que eu não sei como chamar, mas são sensacionais](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

**Depois, um lugar para desenvolvedores conseguirem *empregos*.**

Nós percebemos que, mesmo com programadores talentosos sendo difíceis de se encontrar por aí, a maioria dos sites de empregos eram voltados para empresas de recrutamento. Assim, eles acabavam repletos de vagas falsas para "startups inovadoras", e empregos para pessoas com "8 anos de experiência com Swift". Esses sites não atendiam ninguém. Alguém tinha que fazer alguma coisa a respeito disso e daí nasceu o [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/why-stack). Mas agora o organograma não tinha lugar para o Careers... O Joel não se importava. Ele continuava dizendo que

> "Nosso trabalho não é desenhar. Nosso trabalho é seguir servindo à comundiade de desenvolvedores, **incansavelmente**. Arruma isso logo antes que eu jogue seu monitor extra fora e te proíba de pegar sobremesa."

Apesar da pressão, eu continuei sem saber onde colocar o Careers no gráfico. No final das contas eu coloquei em qualquer lugar, e desenhei um Batman do lado porque **ele é incansável como a gente**:

[image: Nanananananananananananananan Batman!]

**E depois? Aos desenvolvedores *TUDO*!**

E cá estamos. Nós até poderíamos continuar nos parabenizando por um trabalho bem feito. Eu cheguei até a planejar uma festa de auto-parabenização, mas o Joel não aprovou a ideia. Ele disse:

> "Sabe quando a gente vai dar uma festa? Quando *todos* os problemas que afetam a vida dos programadores forem resolvidos. Semana passada o John Carmack reclamou de um sanduíche no Instagram. *ONDE VOCÊ ESTAVA QUE DEIXOU ISSO ACONTECER?*"

As vezes eu me preocupo com o Joel, mas ele tem um pouco de razão:

#### A vida de programador não é fácil

Nosso foco sempre foi ajudar programadores do mundo todo a resolver os problemas que afetavam seu dia a dia. Acho que se, anos atrás, nós tentassemos construir a melhor plataforma de perguntas e respostas para *todo mundo*, ela teria sido um fracasso. Foi só porque decidimos atender às necessidades de um único grupo que conseguimos tomar as decisões certas, que fizeram do projeto um sucesso.

Então vamos continuar nesse caminho. Vamos continuar focados no que sabemos fazer melhor: resolver os problemas dos programadores. Hoje nós estamos trabalhando na maior expansão da nossa plataforma desde o lançamento do Stack Overflow: Documentação. Você pode [saber mais a respeito aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), ou [se inscrever para o beta](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform) e nos ajudar nessa empreitada.

Também é importante dizer que não é sempre que fazemos as coisas direito. Mas todo sucesso até hoje se deu graças ao nosso foco em melhorar a vida de programadores e programadoras. Nós vamos sempre buscar transferir esse sucesso para outras áreas, sempre que possível, mas nossa atenção está sempre voltada para as necessidades desenvolvedores como vocês e espero que vocês continuem nos ajudando por muito tempo.

Então é assim que nós estamos organizados hoje:

[image: Bem organizado]

Será que um dia vamos ter mais quadradinhos coloridos do lado dos outros produtos? Espero que sim, mas só o tempo dirá se isso vai realmente acontecer. Como sempre, sua participação é fundamental para desenharmos nosso futuro.

### Você disse que a logo mudou...

Verdade. A logomarca do Stack Overflow, que todos nós conhecemos e amamos, praticamente não mudou desde o nosso [concurso no 99 Designs](http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774/entries) que pagou US$512 ao vencedor - e isso era *muito* dinheiro pra gente naquela época. Ela tem um lugar especial no nosso coração, então nossa equipe de design fez apenas algumas mudanças bem simples. Semana que vem eles vão entrar em maiores detalhes sobre como ela se encaixa no nosso novo guia de design, que vai nos ajudar a padronizar nossa identidade visual e agilizar o nosso trabalho de design.

Nós também retiramos inspiração de como o Google explicou o conceito de "letra de livro infantil quase alinhada corretamente" por trás da sua nova marca, e decidimos fazer nosso próprio vídeo! Nosso vídeo pode não ter o mesmo nível de saudosismo da época em que a gente tinha hora da soneca na escolinha, mas acho que ele explica bem as mudanças na nossa logo:

[image: Design feito por unicórnios] https://youtu.be/uipTZ2re4Uk

(Filme: Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe, aka [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha?tab=profile); Música: [Zero Project](https://www.jamendo.com/en/artist/340121/zero-project))

#### Nós somos o Stack Overflow. E não seríamos nada sem vocês.

---

<sup>Post por [Jay Hanlon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14/jaydles). O original [aqui](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/)</sup>

Comment: Acho legal recebermos camisas da empresa nova.  :D

Comment: E agora nosso logo no menu da rede é verde.

Comment: Eu vim aqui dar +1 só pelo desenho do Batman.

Comment: Mentira. Parabéns pela nova organização. Acho que ela faz muito sentido.

Comment: [Ué, antes eram contra mudar o ícone, agora todos estão amando?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148/75)... =s

Comment: A partir de agora vou passar a dizer "o SO" para o site, "a SO" para a empresa e "a SE" para a rede. Beleza?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown 5 votos contra mudar o logo agora é "todo mundo"?! :P

Comment: Nem acredito que faço parte disso. Eu gosto disso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Isso. Mas a gente pode complicar ainda mais no futuro...

Comment: Aquele quadro "documentação" está  relacionado com [isso aqui](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/4056678)?

Comment: @renan Exatamente. O projeto tá caminhando e ainda falta um tanto pra ficar pronto, mas a ideia é que *eventualmente* ele faça parte do nosso site também.

Comment: Pra mim o Stack Overflow é um Yahoo! Respostas melhorado. Sem mais.

Comment: @DiegoSouza Uh... obrigado, eu acho?

Comment: @DiegoSouza Eu vejo o Yahoo Respostas assim: http://blog.codinghorror.com/whos-your-arch-enemy/

Comment: Vai demorar um pouco pra eu me acostumar, mas eu gostei que a logo dos SOs em português, japonês, russo, etc sejam substancialmente diferentes [em cores] umas das outras. Quem sabe assim o pessoal confunde menos um site com o outro...

Comment: @mgibsonbr [Não adiantou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87127/phonegap-is-not-working). Só se o logo grande lá do topo fosse verde mesmo. Mas aí seria um site palmeirense...

Comment: Eu só *participo* do Stack, trabalhar, alguns poucos.

Comment: Pô, @Diego, Y Respostas é florida... sem brincadeira, comparação terrível...

Comment: E esse [pônei maldito](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3yGSJE53kU) na história da logo? :v

Comment: Pensei que o novo nome fosse [skeet overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9151/238766) :D

Comment: @KaduAmaral Na SE, ops, SO, eles têm um lance com unicórnios...

Comment: Até hoje acho que o Design do Stack Overflow devia mudar, ficar um estilo mais moderno... adaptar ao Windows 10.... sei lá, iria ficar bonito e mais atraente.

Comment: Eita, isso significa então que a camiseta que ganhei já está [deprecared]?

Comment: @OnoSendai Não... agora ela é *vintage*!

Comment: @Gabe 0_o verdade...

Comment: @OnoSendai Marketing é tudo nessa vida `:D`

Comment: @Gabe stackexchange.com já passou o nytimes.com rs 46º!! :D

Comment: Depois de ver o vídeo da mudança de logo você se dá conta que está naquela parte estranha da internet e é melhor desligar o PC e ir dormir.