# "O Stack Exchange" ou "a Stack Exchange"?

Tags: debate

Stack Exchange é algo novo e está crescendo muito a cada dia. São vários sites como o Stack Overflow, askubuntu, Stack Overflow PT, Portuguese Language, etc que possuem a mesma lógica de funcionamento, mas ganham design próprio.

Podemos dizer que Stack Exchange é uma rede de site ou um portal?

Rede de site é um expressão nova?

Qual seria a melhor definição?

Comment: Não fui eu quem deu o -1, mas tem um monte de problemas na pergunta. "Algo novo" em tempo de internet, definitivamente não é. Outra coisa, a rede agora é Stack Overflow. **A** rede e **O** site tem o mesmo nome. E as respostas para isto estão por todo o site, basta ler a documentação, os blogs, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meu entendimento é "a". É a empresa, ainda que agora [ela deva ser chamada de Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4354/101). É a rede de sites. Não tem nada de portal aqui. Alias, este é um dos termos mais mal usados que já vi. Não é o mais porque nossa área é ótima de usar termos de forma errada.

Comment: Só um aparte como disse o @Bacco, também pode ser **o** site. Tipo "Onde viste isso? Vi no Stack Overflow".

Comment: Mas ele perguntou sobre Stack Exchange. Ainda que possa ser o site também, ninguém ala dele :D http://stackexchange.com E talvez, só talvez, este site seja um portal para os outros :)

Comment: Eu gostei da mudança do nome, porque trouxe uma mudança de filosofia e foco interessante, mas ficou esquisito chamar o site que não é único e a empresa pelo mesmo nome. Eu acho que tem uma solução boa. Claro que não vão fazer isto. Deixa de lado tudo o que não é o foco e centraliza tudo em um site chamado SO e ponto (poderia ter as versões em línguas diferentes. Eu até admitiria ter outros assuntos em sites separados c/ o selo SO. Ex.: Stack Overflow - Math (ou Science em geral), SO Ubuntu, SO - Users, mais pelo legado. Foco do que é bom. Concentração de esforços no que importa.

Comment: O esquema do nome igual ao site é meio contra intuitivo, mas nossa ideia é que a *Rede Stack Exchange*, é um dos serviços prestados pela *empresa Stack Overflow*. A empresa tem um site de programação, um serviço de vagas de emprego, e uma rede de sites de perguntas e respostas. É confuso, mas eu gosto do nome novo. Faz mais sentido.

Comment: No longo prazo, talvez deixe de fazer sentido usar Stack Exchange. Rede Stack Overflow poderia funcionar. @Gabe

Answer (score 13):

Acho que isso se encaixa em [silepse de gênero](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silepse#Silepse_de_g.C3.AAnero).

Em exemplos:

"A empresa StackOverflow"

"O site StackOverflow"

"A rede StackOverflow"

Quando refiro-me apenas ao nome, utilizo na forma masculina.

"O StackOverflow"

Num outro exemplo, é comum ver brasileiros dizendo "A Google". Para mim soa estranho. Eu sempre penso como "O Google". Mas então temos uma silepse de gênero quando há um *substantivo comum* de gênero diferente do *substantivo próprio*:

"A empresa Google"

Não há um consenso sobre se está certo ou errado dizer "A Google" pois pode ser interpretado como uma abreviação de "A empresa Google". O mesmo se dá para o caso do StackOverflow.

Veja como é curioso o uso: https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/?hl=pt

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há casos curiosos como "Microsoft". Eu vejo como "A Microsoft" pois soa estranho dizer "O Microsoft".